# How to get a field value and multiply it to get price in a PriceResolver

Tags: 8, commerce

Getting my feet wet with price resolvers, and I have figured out how to set a new price for all entities that have `field_discount_percentage`. I am then getting the price and multiplying it for the sake of this example by .95 to get a 5% discount.

```
public function resolve(PurchasableEntityInterface $entity, $quantity, Context $context) {
  if ($entity instanceof ProductVariationInterface && $entity->hasField('field_discount_percentage')) {
    return $entity->getPrice()->multiply('0.95');
  }
}
```

What I trying to do, is to use `->getValue` or  `->getString` for the `field_dicount_percentage` so that I can set the percentage value in the field from the front end.

```
public function resolve(PurchasableEntityInterface $entity, $quantity, Context $context) {
  if ($entity instanceof ProductVariationInterface && $entity->hasField('field_discount_percentage')) {

    //here is where i would like to create a variable for the number value of the field, but I get lost...
    $discount = $entity->get('field_discount_percentage')->getValue()[0]['value'];

    // I have also tried this
    $discount = $entity->get('field_discount_percentage')->getString();

    return $entity->getPrice()->multiply($discount);
  }
}
```

I am getting empty quotes back from `$discount = $entity->get('field_discount_percentage')->getString();` which is making me wonder if I cannot use a variable to a numerical field value.

> InvalidArgumentException: The provided value "" is not a numeric
> value. in Drupal\commerce_price\Calculator::assertNumberFormat() (line
> 261 of
> MY-Site\web\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\price\src\Calculator.php).

So what is the best way to do this in a Drupal commerce context?

Any help would be appreciated.
:)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by checking that `field_discount_percentage` is not empty, rather than just checking if the entity has `field_discount_percentage`. The error must have been from all the other entities that were returning empty fields as a non-numerical value of `""`

```
public function resolve(PurchasableEntityInterface $entity, $quantity, Context $context) {
  if ($entity instanceof ProductVariationInterface && !$entity->get('field_discount_percentage')->isEmpty()) {
     $discount = $entity->get('field_discount_percentage')->getValue()[0]['value'];
     return $entity->getPrice()->multiply($discount);
  }
}
```